# MacPorts not working after power outage during build (sqlite disk I/O error)

Tags: macports, sqlite

I was building packages in MacPorts on a Mac Mini when the power went out. Now anything I try to do in MacPorts (`install`, `clean`, `selfupdate`) results in the following error:

```
sqlite error: disk I/O error (3850) while executing query: ATTACH DATABASE '/opt/local/var/macports/registry/registry.db' AS registry
    while executing
"registry::open $db_path"
    (procedure "mportinit" line 610)
    invoked from within
"mportinit ui_options global_options global_variations"
Error: /opt/local/bin/port: Failed to initialize MacPorts, sqlite error: disk I/O error (3850) while executing query: ATTACH DATABASE '/opt/local/var/macports/registry/registry.db' AS registry
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I would restore from backup as a fie is corrupt and that file depends on the pros you have installed and can't be reproduced from a new install

Comment: @Mark I don't have any backups for this particular machine. Any other ideas?

Comment: The way to reinstall macports is to have a list of the ports you installed and then redo - to get the list of pros you need that db. So no - just take this as a learning moment and realise you need backups. You can reinstall macports from scratch if you know which ones you need

Comment: @Mark Both `port list installed` and `port -qv installed` result in the same error. Is there a way to get a list of installed ports outside of macports?

Comment: No as that list is held in the database that is corrupted.

Comment: @Mark Hmm... it looks like `/opt/local/var/macports/registry/portfiles/` has a directory for each of my ports, maybe I could use that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for this is actually quite simple, and is mentioned in [this MacPorts issue](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/32686). From a comment on the issue by "pixilla@…":

```
$ cd /opt/local/var/macports/registry
$ ls registry.db-journal                                                                                                                                                                             
$ sudo sqlite3 registry.db
sqlite> .tables
sqlite> SELECT id FROM ports;
sqlite> .quit
```

Based on another comment by "ecronin@…", I conclude that, had I run any `port` command as root, it would have been fixed automatically and saved me all this trouble. But I always forget to use `sudo`...

**EDIT** Wait, I did run a `port` command with `sudo`. Weird. Oh, well, at least it works now.

Comment: Same thing happened to me.  Power out during an install.  I get a straight sqlite error, but there is no journal file.  `sqlite error: database disk image is malformed (11)`.